# Check if an image from an array is selected randomly

Tags: css, arrays, image, random, background

I've got a little code to randomize background pictures inside a div. I want to modify another div's background if a specified image is selected from the array. My code doesnt' work properly.

Here it is

```
var images = [ 'image_2.jpg', 'image_4.jpg', 'image_1.jpg'];
jQuery(' #header-top').css({'background-image': 'url(images/' + images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)] + ')'});

if ( images =="image_1.jpg"){
            jQuery('#promo').css({'background': 'url(images/image_back.jpg' });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`images == "image_1.jpg"` is nonsensical code, it doesn't check for anything. You want to check and see if your selected image is the one chosen by the random generator, so you have to compare the number to the index of the image in the array.

```
var images = [ 'image_2.jpg', 'image_4.jpg', 'image_1.jpg'];
var imageNumber = [Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)];
jQuery(' #header-top').css({'background-image': 'url(images/' + images[imageNumber] + ')'});

if (imageNumber == 2){
        jQuery('#promo').css({'background': 'url(images/image_back.jpg' });
}
```

Comment: It works fine. Thank you. Your code is missing a "]" second line.

Comment: fixed the "]", and I'm glad to help

Comment: The code works fine infFirefox ( the browser I use)  but I seems no to work on Chrome. Strange.... any explanation for such behaviour?

Comment: Not off the top of my head......can you determine which line specifically is failing and what version of chrome you are on?

Comment: When the condition is fulfilled the backround image is not replaced. 
My Chrome version:
42.0.2311.90 (64-bit), running on a Mac OSX 10.6.8

Comment: Lol... the condition is missing a round bracket at url... that was the problem... it's funny because Firefox jumped over it!

Comment: Ahhhhhhhh I'm glad it was just a simple typo, I was really confused as to what was going wrong!